# Can we use Solidity with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I want to develop a blockchain system with smart contract using NodeJs for blockchain and Solidity for smart contract, i Google'd this but i found no answer ?

actually, i developped a blockchain system using javascript and new langage for smart contract, but this langage doesn't contain a lot of instruction so using solidity will be very useful, i wonder if possible to user solidity on blockchain chains which are developped by javascript ?

And if there is any post contains a description of how using that.
Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Here is an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/solc) for solidity in javascript. I hope this is of some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, you use `truffle` to compile to contract to JSON file and then import it to your Javascript code and use it.

https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/compiling-contracts

- First, you `truffle compile` to generate your json file
- Import the json file to your code
- `const your_contract = web3.eth.contract(contract.json.abi)`
- `const contract = your_contract.at(<your_contract_address)`

And then after that, you can use your contract's methods. 
`contract.<your_function>`

Comment: This is incorrect. The JSON file produced by truffle only contains the bytecode, ABI, and other related metadata. You cannot actually execute it unless your Javsacript-based blockchain includes an evm within it.

Comment: @RaghavSood You can `import <your_contract> from './<your_contract.json>'` and then use its method. But you will need to use `web3.eth.contract(<your_contract>.abi)` before you use methods and functions

Comment: @QuangVõ  In the 2nd. bullet point of your answer you wrote: `Import the json file to your code`.  Well just how exactly do you do that? Is there a way to automate this process, so that after each compilation of your contract - which will create a new `JSON` file - that `JSON` file will automatically get loaded into your `Javascript` code? (And I'm not talking about using `Node.JS`, but rather just plain vanilla `Javascript`)

Comment: @Sirab33 this automation seems like something you would need to handle on your own, but definitely seems doable