# node - How to generate NFT token for a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, token, nft

I'm reading about NFT tokens. It seems an interesting way to sign media online and I want to do some experiments. Is there any node-js implementation to add nft generation inside web or electron apps?
I'ts not clear for me if the [ÈRC-721](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/standards/tokens/erc-721/) standard can be implemented in javascript. Any info about?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we use Solidity with NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59048312/can-we-use-solidity-with-nodejs)

Answer (score 4):

The ERC-721 defines a [Solidity](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/) interface. Solidity is a language that compiles into EVM-compatible bytecode (EVM stands for Ethereum Virtual Machine).

And since smart contracts run on EVM, you need to use some language that compiles to EVM-compatible bytecode, such as Solidity or Vyper... *Or you can write the bytecode directly in binary, if you you want. :)*

There's currently no reliable compiler from Javascript to EVM bytecode. So Javascript would not be a good choice, and I'd really recommend writing the implementation in Solidity or Vyper.

Comment: I never used that languages. I suppose that the EVM needs to run on a server right, it use the ethereum infrastructure?

Comment: @newbiedev EVM runs on each Ethereum node. So you could call it a server, yes. However, you can use an EVM emulator in [Remix IDE](http://remix.ethereum.org/) or [Ganache](https://www.trufflesuite.com/ganache) for local development, so you don't need to install a full Ethereum node to run smart contracts locally.