# Can I connect solidity contract with backend Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ethereum, solidity, erc721

I am a beginner, Can anyone please guide me that how can I connect my smart contract (erc721) with node.js. Please guide through steps or links. Thanks a lot.

Comment: [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59048312/can-we-use-solidity-with-nodejs)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start developing smart contracts in a local network and test those contracts you should use these frameworks: [truffle](https://trufflesuite.com/) and [hardhat](https://hardhat.org/). You may check out both of them but and the end you will use only one, so the one you like the most.

And the libraries you should use to interact with smart contracts using NodeJS are: [web3](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/) or [ethers](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/).

Comment: Is web3 documentation helpful for this?

Comment: @ZohaAkram absolutely

Comment: I have my node js application but i dont know how to write web3 code in that so that it can integrate with my smart contract

Comment: I can not find any resource for integration with backend

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can interact with smart contract on server side nodejs
You can choose etherjs and web3js.
For web3

1. import web3
2. import contract ABI and Address
3. Create contract like this :

   const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);
4. call functions like this :
   const result = await contract.methods.functionName(args).call();